# Finding the range of $a$

Tags: functions, quadratics

> Let $f: \mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{R}$  be defined as $f(x)= \dfrac{x^2 + 2x+a}{x^2 +4x +3a},$ where D and R denote the domain of $f $ and the set of all real numbers respectively. If $f$ is surjective mapping then the range of $a$ is?

Attempt:

Set $y=\dfrac{x^2 + 2x+a}{x^2 +4x +a} $\

We get a quadratic in x: $$ x^2(y-1)+ x(4y-2)+3ay -a=0 $$, setting its discriminant $\ge 0$, I get $a \in (-\infty,0]\cup{[1, \infty)}$

But coefficient of $x$ $\ne 0$ $\implies a \ne \frac 4 3$

Intersection of the 2 sets, doesn't give the right answer for $a$, how do I solve it then?

Comment: Why do you say "But coefficient of x has to be positive"? A slight alternative: rewrite your expression as $$1  - \frac{2x}{x^2 + 4x + a},$$, which you get by doing long division. Note that the second term, if the denominator is always positive, will be *bounded*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $D$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is well-defined.

Set $\displaystyle y=\frac{x^2+2x+a}{x^2+4x+3a}$.

Case (1) If $x^2+2x+a=0$ and $x^2+4x+3a=0$ have a common root $x=x_0$. Then $y$ can be written as

$$y=\frac{(x-x_0)(x+2+x_0)}{(x-x_0)(x+4+x_0)}=\frac{x+2+x_0}{x+4+x_0}$$

$y$ cannot be equal to $1$ and hence $f$ is not surjective.

$x^2+2x+a=0$ and $x^2+4x+3a=0$ have a common root $x=x_0$ when $x_0^2+2x_0+a=0=x_0^2+4x_0+3a$.This implies that $x_0=-a$.

So, $(-a)^2+2(-a)+a=0$.

$a=0$ or $a=1$.

Case (2) If $x^2+2x+a=0$ and $x^2+4x+3a=0$ does not have a common root. The $a\ne0$ and $a\ne1$

We have $(y-1)x^2+(4y-2)x+3ay-a=0$. As $x$ is real,

\begin{align*}
(4y-2)^2-4(y-1)(3ay-a)&\ge0\\
4y^2-4y+1-3ay^2+4ay-a&\ge0\\
(4-3a)y^2+(4a-4)y+(1-a)&\ge0
\end{align*}

The above inequality in $y$ should be satisfied by all $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

So, we need $4-3a>0$ and $(4a-4)^2-4(4-3a)(1-a)\le0$. Therefore, $\displaystyle a<\frac{4}{3}$ and

\begin{align*}
4a^2-8a+4-4+7a-3a^2&\le0\\
a^2-a&\le0\\
0\le a&\le1
\end{align*}

$f$ is surjective if and only if $\displaystyle 0< a<1$.

Comment: Thanks. Please explain why would it be that if they have a common root then f is not surjective.

Comment: If $x_0$ is a common root, then $y$ can be written as $\frac{x+2+x_0}{x+4+x_0}$. $y$ cannot be $1$ as it will lead to $x+2+x_0=x+4+x_0$. The range of $f$ is then $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$. So, it is not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is surjective then for every $y\in\Bbb{R}$ there exists $x\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$, or equivalently
$$(y-1)x^2+2(2y-1)x+(3y-1)a=0.$$
This implies the discriminant of this quadratic in $x$ has nonnegative discriminant, where
$$D=4(2y-1)^2-4(y-1)(3y-1)a.$$
Hence for all $y\in\Bbb{R}$ we must have
$$(y-1)(3y-1)a\leq(2y-1)^2.$$
For $y=\frac{1}{3}$ and $y=1$ this holds independently of $a$.
For $y\in(\frac{1}{3},1)$ this is equivalent to
$$a\geq\frac{(2y-1)^2}{(y-1)(3y-1)}.$$
For both $y<\frac{1}{3}$ and $y>1$ this is equivalent to
$$a\leq\frac{(2y-1)^2}{(y-1)(3y-1)}.$$
Some basic calculus shows that the extrema of the right hand side are at $y=0$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}$, taking the values $1$ and $0$ respectively. Its limits as $y$ tends to $\pm\infty$ are $\pm\frac{3}{2}$, so these are a local minimum and a local maximum, respectively. Hence the range for $a$ is the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks but the answer is $(0,1)$